# Building complex calculated model in Javascript

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, model

I'm working on a tabletop RPG character builder as a hobby/to expand my skillset. Part of the challenge is the complex model needed to represent the character's stats, feats, attacks, etc., most of which can affect each other.

For example, given the simplified character below, it's easy to calculate what the "attack" value should be.

```
character = {
   strength: 14,
   dexterity: 16,
   base_attack_bonus: 3,
   attack: function() { return this.strength + this.base_attack_bonus; }
}
```

However, to be complete, the character builder has to account for feats like "Weapon Finesse," which make a character's attacks use dexterity instead of strength to calculate the attack value.

I began this project when Object.observe() was still in the future for Javascript, so for maximum flexibility, I opted for an event-driven web of dependencies (with precautions to prevent loops). I created a "Data" object which could `depend()` its properties on the properties of another object.

Something like this:

```
character = new Data({
   strength: 14,
   dexterity: 16,
   attack_modifier: 0,
   base_attack_bonus: 3,
   attack: function() { return this.attack_modifier + this.base_attack_bonus; }
});
character.depend("attack_modifier", character, "strength")
// Weapon Finesse feat rules:
character.undepend("attack_modifier", character, "strength")
character.depend("attack_modifier", character, "dexterity")
```

If the strength or dexterity scores changed at some later point, the attack_modifier property that depended on them would be updated instantaneously (thanks to `Object.observe()`) as well, trickling on down the chain. If a property is `depend()`ed on more than one property, by default, it updates to the sum of all its dependencies - but the `update()` function is customizable, so you could return a list of all its dependencies, or the largest, etc.

This lets me create complex unordered dependency chains, and yet allows feats and abilities to be created after the fact to change nearly any aspect of the character without altering the model's code. Theoretically, it should also improve performance over recalculating every part of the model when something changes.

I'm now weighing my options since `Object.observe()` and `Array.observe()` have been outmoded. I could use a shim and keep going. But if I'm revisiting the situation anyway, I thought I'd cast around and see if there's a better design pattern for this kind of work.

I guess there are two questions here:

1. Is it better (for the above case) to use an `Object.observe()` and `Array.observe()` shim; to develop my own Observer implementation; or to use another third-party option?
2. Is the dependency web described above a reasonable design pattern for a complex yet flexible model like this, or am I making things way too difficult for myself? Is there a better way?

Comment: If you're comfortable with `Object.observe()`, take a look at http://reactivex.io/. And here's a great course up on egghead: https://egghead.io/series/step-by-step-async-javascript-with-rxjs. I stumbled over this a couple months ago looking for something unrelated, but was astounded at what you could do with RxJs.

Answer (score 1):

You could always build the complex model and refactor until it's as elegant as you want it. Assuming you want to calculate damage with a function outside of the character object, you could start with something like this to get the ball rolling and just use iterative improvement from there.

```
character = {
   strength: 14,
   dexterity: 16,
   base_attack_bonus: 3,
   inventory: [{ weaponId: 0,
                 description: 'fist',
                 punch: 5 },
               { weaponId: 1,
                 description: 'wooden sword',
                 stab: 7,
                 weight: 10 }],
   equipped: 1,
   skills: { punch: 15,
             stab: 17 },
   attack: function() { return attackModify(this.equipped, this.skills) +
                         this.base_attack_bonus; }
}
```

Then you would be able to implement weapon finesse and other feats outside of the character object. Starting out complex is better than not starting at all. Once you have time to play with the code you'll see ways to make it simpler. Then it should be no problem applying the Observer pattern or whatever you see fit once you've tamed the beast. You might find that if you force the code to fit some pattern from the get-go that you would have been better off using some other GOF design. Design will emerge through refactoring initial brute-force efforts.

The bottom line is that you obviously want to build a complex model. I think you should feel free to do so if it makes you happy. Then just focus your initial efforts on refactoring rather than patterns. You'll need the simplicity achieved from refactoring to more easily fit your code into a pattern in the future.